# Missing Pixel When Loading Texture?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to load a 3x10 image, using only 1 byte per "pixel". This pixel is a single alpha.

When i load the image as follows, every fourth pixel is discarded for some reason. No opengl errors, I have non-power of 2 hardware support.

So if i have the following pixel buffer: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, the image will look like this:

```
0 1 2
4 5 6
8 9 10
...
```

Texture load code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA8, 3, 10, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I'm not really sure what is happening, I am stumped. Is there anything that can be causing such behavior? I have the latest opengl drivers as well...

Comment: Is there some sort of internal limit? I see it adding 4 bytes each row, instead of the 3 it is suppose to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` pixel storage value controls row alignment of the texture data passed to `glTexImage2D()`. The default value is 4.

Since your data has 3 bytes per row, this will be rounded up to the next multiple of 4, which is 4. So with the default value, `glTexImage2D()` will read 4 bytes per row.

To make this work, the row alignment value has to be changed to 1:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, does the setting stay for all other texture loads, or is it only for the next upload?

Comment: This is a global setting. It will stay in effect for the context until you change it to a different value.